# Как сделать наклонные платформы в 2d играх?

Tags: разработка-игр, 2d

Вроде бы смещается, но проваливается в текстуры. Вот картинка по принципу которой я хочу сделать наклонные платформы, не привязываясь к языку и библиотеке, на которой написана игра.

[image]

Comment: Смотря в каком движке ты делаешь игру

Comment: Попробую предположить, что движок самописный, а вопрос теоретический про архитектуру, не привязанный к конкретным технологиям

Comment: Да, я бы хотел узнать как в общем случае реализовать наклонные платформы

Comment: @ПавелЧемармазович допишите уточнение в сам вопрос ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/721458/edit))

Comment: Ну так есть способ?